# PHP - Incorrect integer value

Tags: php, pdo, phpmyadmin

I am building a speaker form for my website which basically just takes the inputted data from the user and puts it in the database. The website also allows you to save or submit the form and I check that using

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])
```

The problem I getting is, when i leave some text boxes blank and hit "save", the database gives an error saying this:

```
( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'phone_number' at row 1 in C:\wamp64\www\rotarywebsite\speakerform.php on line 98
```

I checked the code and the database to see if there was something i misspelled or anything else wrong in the database that I found research on. So basically I want the users to be allowed to "save" the form while also leaving some text boxes blank. Here is my code and SQL format

PHP code

```
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
         $fullname = trim($_POST['fullname']);
        $phone_number = trim($_POST['phone-number']);
        $cell_day_of = trim($_POST['cell-dayof']);
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $address = trim($_POST['address']);
        $city = trim($_POST['city']);
        $state = trim($_POST['state']);
        $zip = trim($_POST['zip']);
        $titles = trim($_POST['titles']);
        $company = trim($_POST['company']);
        $affiliations = trim($_POST['affiliations']);
        $website = trim($_POST['website']);
        $topic = trim($_POST['topic']);
        $summary = trim($_POST['summary']);
        $availability = trim($_POST['availability']);
        $notice = trim($_POST['notice']);
        $guest = trim($_POST['guest']);
        $materials = trim($_POST['materials']);
        $projector = trim($_POST['projector']);
        $equipment = trim($_POST['equipment']);
        $educating = trim($_POST['educating']);
        $support = trim($_POST['support']);
        $international = trim($_POST['international']);
        $familiar = trim($_POST['familiar']);
        $member = trim($_POST['member']);
        $allergies = trim($_POST['allergies']);
        $bio = trim($_POST['bio']);
        $introduce = trim($_POST['introduce']);
        $last_need = trim($_POST['last-need']);
        $timestamp = time();
        $stmtUpdate = $handler->prepare("INSERT INTO formdata (user_id, fullname, phone_number, cell_dayof, email, address, city, state, zip, titles, company, affiliations, website, topic, summary, availability, notice, guest, materials, projector, equipment, educating, support, international, familiar, member, allergies, bio, introduce, last_need, time_stamp)VALUES(:userid, :fullname, :phone_number, :cell_dayof, :email, :address, :city, :state, :zip, :titles, :company, :affiliations, :website, :topic, :summary, :availability, :notice, :guest, :materials, :projector, :equipment, :educating, :support, :international, :familiar, :member, :allergies, :bio, :introduce, :last_need, :timestamp)");
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':fullname', $fullname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':phone_number', $phone_number, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':cell_dayof', $cell_dayof, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':address', $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':city', $city, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':state', $state, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':zip', $zip, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':titles', $titles, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':company', $company, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':affiliations', $affiliations, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':website', $website, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':topic', $topic, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':summary', $summary, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':availability', $availability, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':notice', $notice, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':guest', $guest, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':materials', $materials, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':projector', $projector, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':equipment', $equipment, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':educating', $educating, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':support', $support, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':international', $international, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':familiar', $familiar, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':member', $member, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':allergies', $allergies, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':bio', $bio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':introduce', $introduce, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':last_need', $last_need, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmtUpdate->bindParam(':timestamp', $timestamp, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmtUpdate->execute();
    }
```

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `formdata` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fullname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` int(200) NOT NULL,
  `cell_dayof` int(200) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `zip` int(200) NOT NULL,
  `titles` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `affiliations` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `website` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `topic` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `summary` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `availability` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `notice` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `guest` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `materials` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `projector` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `equipment` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `educating` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `support` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `international` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `familiar` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `member` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `allergies` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `bio` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `introduce` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `last_need` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `time_stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: You have an empty string in `$_POST['phone_number']`.

Comment: You shouldn't store phone numbers as `INT`, store them as `VARCHAR`.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['phone-number'])` show?

Comment: @Barmar where is the empty string? and i will try that

Comment: The error message says `Incorrect integer value: ''`. That means the value you're trying to store into the `phone_number` column is `''`, which isn't a number.

Comment: Thats weird because i leave it empty. OHH do you think the database doesnt allow null int values? because i did the same for VARCHAR values and it worked

Comment: It's not null, it's an empty string. What INT value do you expect it to store for that?

Comment: phone number and other stuff. In the other file i did VARCHAR and it was email and name and it worked when an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `phone_number` is declared as an `INT` field, you have to provide a valid integer value for it, and an empty string is not a valid integer.

You could replace empty strings with `0`.

```
$phone_number = trim($_POST['phone_number']);
if ($phone_number == '') {
    $phone_number = 0;
}
```

But the best solution would be to change this field in the database to `VARCHAR`. Phone numbers are not really numbers, they often have other characters, e.g. `+1 (202) 555-1212`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You have all fields in the DB set to NOT NULL. This means that an insert statement must contain a valid value for every single field. You will need to drop the NOT NULL constraints from the those fields that you want to be optional.

Comment: I tested this with another file and it was set to NOT NULL and they sent perfectly fine

Comment: An empty string is not the same as `NULL`.

Comment: NOT NULL means literally that a value must be inserted for that field or else the insert statement will be denied. If it worked previously, then you must have been inserting a valid value in to each field.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the NOT NULL from the attributes you want to keep empty at times.
eg-
**try changing -**  `fullname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
                `phone_number` int(200) NOT NULL, 
**to -**
 `fullname` varchar(200) ,
  `phone_number` int (200),

Comment: An empty string is not the same thing as `NULL`.